# How do I check whether input string contains any spaces?

Tags: java, regex

I have a input dialog that asks for XML element name, and I want to check it to see if it has any spaces.

can I do something like name.matches()?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Why use a regex?

```
name.contains(" ")
```

That should work just as well, and be faster.

Comment: This works if there is JUST ONE whitespace. But, what if the text string has multiple successive whitespaces ("    ")?
Using regex provides you with a failsafe for conditions like this as well.

Comment: @AbhineetKumar what do you mean? this works for me, stackoverflow doesn't render multiple spaces but this works with multiple spaces as well ->     `String withSpace = "foo            foo";
    assert(withSpace.contains(" "));`

Comment: this matches all whitespace chars?

Comment: We use regex because there are so many space characters around the world. In Chinese and Japanese you will likely only encounter the ideographic space, and will never match " ". So rather than inventing your own duplicate list of all the possible whitespace characters, and changing that list as your software is distributed to more regions, you can use the regex from day one and know it's universally correct.

Comment: you can use StringUtils.containsWhitespace(CharSequence seq) from lang3 library

Answer (score 14):

If you will use Regex, it already has a predefined character class "\S" for any non-whitespace character.

```
!str.matches("\\S+")
```

tells you if this is a string of at least one character where all characters are non-whitespace

Comment: str.matches("\\s+")

Comment: @Frank, no that matches a string that *only* contains 1 or more whitespace characters.

Comment: This is useful for checking whitespace in user names.

Comment: Great answer, but it incorrectly finds empty strings contain spaces. It can easily be combined with a length check such as (!str.matches("\\S+") && (str.length() > 0)) to be a fully correct solution

Answer (score 10):

A simple answer, along similar lines to the previous ones is:

```
str.matches(".*\\s.*")
```

- The first ".*" says that there can be zero or more instances of any character in front of the space.
- The "\\s" says it must contain any whitespace character.
- The last ".*" says there can be zero or more instances of any character after the space.

When you put all those together, this returns true if there are one or more whitespace characters anywhere in the string.

Here is a simple test you can run to benchmark your solution against:

```
boolean containsWhitespace(String str){
    return str.matches(".*\\s.*");
}

String[] testStrings = {"test", " test", "te st", "test ", "te   st", 
                        " t e s t ", " ", "", "\ttest"};
for (String eachString : testStrings) {
        System.out.println( "Does \"" + eachString + "\" contain whitespace? " + 
                             containsWhitespace(eachString));
}
```

Comment: Static code analysis complains, that this regular expression is potentially vulnerable to backtracking attacks.

Comment: The backtracking in a regex occurs because the match gets re-computed over and over trying to find the one that matches the most data. This warning occurs in this example since str.matches(".*\\s.*") as two "greedy" matches.  Processing huge amounts of data could take significant time.  Like most lint warnings we should learn and improve. You can change to use non-greedy matches by changing .* to (.*?)   So the final one would be: str.matches("(.*?)\\s(.*?)");  Effectively this stops looking for matches when it hits the first space in the string,  instead of the last. It's a great improvement.

Answer (score 5):

```
string name = "Paul Creasey";
if (name.contains(" ")) {

}
```

Comment: can i use this:

boolean space = name.matches(".*\\s+.*");

Comment: @CheaIndian No. Unnecessary regexes are bad.

Comment: @Chea: Unfortunately you can't. But you can upvote multiple answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (str.indexOf(' ') >= 0)
```

would be (slightly) faster.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a regex, you can use this one:

```
str.matches(".*([ \t]).*")
```

In the sense that everything matching this regex is not a valid xml tag name:

```
if(str.matches(".*([ \t]).*")) 
      print "the input string is not valid"
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is tested in android 7.0 up to android 10.0 and it works**

Use these codes to check if string contains space/spaces may it be in the first position, middle or last:

```
 name = firstname.getText().toString(); //name is the variable that holds the string value

 Pattern space = Pattern.compile("\\s+");
 Matcher matcherSpace = space.matcher(name);
 boolean containsSpace = matcherSpace.find();

 if(constainsSpace == true){
  //string contains space
 }
 else{
  //string does not contain any space
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to check whether the input string contains any spaces?

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the string...");
    String s1=sc.nextLine();
    int l=s1.length();
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
        char c=s1.charAt(i);
        if(c==' ')
        {
        System.out.println("spaces are in the position of "+i);
        System.out.println(count++);
        }
        else
        {
        System.out.println("no spaces are there");
    }
}
```

Comment: This code not does not meet OP's requirements and contains flaws.  It seems to be an attempt to re-implement standard method `contains` of the String class which just prints a lot of redundant output instead of returning a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a string does not contain any whitespaces, you can use

```
string.matches("^\\S*$")
```

Example:

```
"name"        -> true
"  "          -> false
"name xxname" -> false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex “\\s”

Example program to count number of spaces **(Java 9 and above)**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);        
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("stackoverflow is a good place to get all my answers");        

    long matchCount = matcher.results().count();   
 
    if(matchCount > 0) 
      System.out.println("Match found " + matchCount + " times.");           
    else 
      System.out.println("Match not found");        
  }
}
```

For **Java 8 and below** you can use matcher.find() in a while loop and increment the count. For example,

```
int count = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
  count ++;
}
```